# How to save momentum during training in Keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, keras

I want to be able to save the state of training my neural net using SGD.  I know I can save the weights using the save_weights function.  What I don't know is how to save the momentum of the gradient decent.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `model.optimizer.get_state()` and `model.optimizer.set_state()` - see https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/454.